# Why should collector voltage need to be higher than emitter voltage?

Tags: bjt

I'm reading up on *npn* (and by extension *pnp*) transistors, and I got tripped up on a note from my book (Practical Electronics for Inventors, 3rd edition, p. 433)

"For an *npn* transistor, the voltage at the collector must be greater than the  voltage at the emitter by at least a few tenths of a volt; otherwise, current will not flow through the collector-emitter junction..."

As far as I'm aware, an *npn* transistor is symmetrical in construction, so it shouldn't matter that the emitter voltage is higher. What is the physical distinction between collector and emitter?

Thanks

Comment: "an npn transistor is symmetrical in construction" That is a complete and utter lie. It's just drawn that way to not melt your brain so early.

Comment: Well, they *can* be constructed symmetrically.. but generally they *aren't*

Comment: Duplicate solved my problem. Guess I just needed to know this was called "reverse action". Thanks